# How to use Oxford Dictionary API in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, dictionary, http

I am a newbie at React. I am trying to build a dictionary web app. I want to use the API provided by Oxford dictionary. I have already registered for the prototype version and gathered the API_ID and API_KEY. I have tried to use the code provided by the Oxford documentation.

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const app_id = "******"; 
  const app_key = "****************";
  const wordId = "ace";
  const fields = "pronunciations";
  const strictMatch = "false";

  const options = {
    host: 'od-api.oxforddictionaries.com',
    port: '443',
    path: '/api/v2/entries/en-gb/' + wordId + '?fields=' + fields + '&strictMatch=' + strictMatch,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'app_id': app_id,
      'app_key': app_key
    }
  };

  axios.get(options, (resp) => {
    let body = '';
    resp.on('data', (d) => {
      body += d;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
      let parsed = JSON.stringify(body);
      console.log(parsed);
    });
  });

  return <div>Hello world!</div>
}

export default App;
```

I am getting the following errors in the console when I run the app.

[image: Console with Errors]

I am not sure what the errors mean. I want to get an object as a result in the console.

Someone kindly help me with this. If there is any more info required from my side, do ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your axios syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Here is a CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-sound-dph2k?file=/src/App.js where I wrapped your API call inisde useEffect(read where to put API call code on reactjs.org)

Comment: As you rightly didn't share the keys my CodeSandbox will catch the error and I have put a console.log for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But then, I'm still stuck. I am facing this error "index.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined". This error appears irrespective of whether I keep or remove the protocol property from the options object. I am also getting the following output in the console "Failed due to invalid keys", even though I am using the correct keys.

Comment: Did you check my CodeSandbox? Check line no 18.

Comment: Yes, I did. Both codesandbox and the localhost are giving out the same errors in the console.

Comment: Try this updated CS with your keys in your local environment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-worker-8u6bx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.get({
  method: "get",
  url: 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-gb/' + wordId + '?fields=' + fields + '&strictMatch=' + strictMatch,,
  headers: {
  'app_id': app_id,
  'app_key': app_key
  }
})
.then(response => { // handle successful response})
.catch(error => { // handle error response})
```

You are using `axios` the wrong way. The code above should work.

Comment: This does not work as you need a protocol - here https - before the url. The oxford dic api doc for node is probably outdated with the `https` module, you should convert it to `axios`. Working solution for [Node is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080318/1705829)

Comment: Hi @Timo. That was a typo. I have made the edit. Let me know if it works here. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, did you try it? The error with missing protocol was just one error that appeared to my brain instant. But there is more. Look at the `axios.get()`. How are parameters defined for data type in `get()`? Hint: check the axios docs, get your code right and then come back here. I will test then. And change your code to `async/await`, much nicer. `then` is ugly..